# CSS Class not working

Tags: html, css

I have a big problme. I programmed a HTML with external .css. 
But all of my  dont working in table.
my  can just working in IE8, but I can not open them in Firefox, Chrome oder IE9 
Please help my :)

My HTML-Codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<title>Ruf zum Sport</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesport.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Ruf zum Sport</h1>
<table border="">
<tr>
<td class="1" id="general">
<p>Auf, ihr steifen und verdorrten<br>
Leute aus B&uuml;ros,<br>
rei&szlig;t euch mal zum Wintersporten<br>
von den &Ouml;fen los.<br>
</p>
</td>

<td class="2" id="general">
<p>Bleiches Volk an Wirtshaustischen<br>
stellt die Gl&auml;ser fort.<br>
Widme dich dem freien, frischen,<br>
frohen Wintersport.
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS-codes:

```
body {
font-family: Comic Sans MS ;
font-size: 13;
font-weight: bold;
word-spacing: 2px;
color: #000000;
margin: 15px auto auto 25px;
line-height: 1cm ;
background: url(ski.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;

}
h1 {
color: #3366FF;
font-size: 2em;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: #0000CC;
border-style: hidden;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
td.1 {
text-align: left;
}

.td.2 {
text-align: right;
padding-left: 70px;
color: #FF66CC;
}

#general {
font-size: 13;
font-weight: bold;
word-spacing: 2px;
line-height: 0.6cm;
}
```

Comment: The string "not working" is not a built-in error message in any browser.

Comment: what exactly is "not working"?

Comment: in <td class="1"> and <td class="2"> the class formation don't word :\

Comment: because class names can't be numbers. also, you want to use id's for those not classes. and general should be a class not an id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

1. A classname, in a CSS class selector, cannot start with a `2` (or any other number)
2. `.td.2` tries to match "An element of any type that is a member of the class `td` and also of the class `2`

Change the class name to something that starts with a letter, and make the `td` a type selector not a class selector.

```
td.two { ... }
```

The second of your problems would have been picked up if you had run your CSS through [a validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), you also have errors in your HTML that would be picked up by a [markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: he also seems to have class and id mixed up

Comment: yes, thank you very much. now, in know where were my problmes :)